# C++ JSON library and Enscripten with JS does not work properly?

Tags: c++, json, reactjs, emscripten

Im having an issue with my project on the JS side.

First I have the json.hpp file from [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) stored in the src directory of my project. When I compile and run my test code in C++ it works great. Here is the C++ code from the bottom up.

**Maps.cpp**

```
// builds all maps initially
Maps::Maps() {
    this->buildMaps();
}

getMap: retrieves a map from array, outputting the string version
string Maps::getMap(int mapNum) {
    nlohmann::json mapJSON = this->makeJSON(mapNum);
    string mapString = mapJSON.dump();
    return mapString;
}

nlohmann::json Maps::makeJSON(int mapNum){
    nlohmann::json json;
    switch(mapNum) {
        case 0:
            json = this->mainMap;
            return json;
        ...
    }
}
...
```

I left out the rest of the code cause this is the only code not working

**Interact.cpp**

```
// constructor doesnt do anything
Interact::Interact() {}

// outputting string since nlohmann::json throws UnboundTypeError in console
string Interact::getMap(int mapNum) {
    Maps gameMaps; //create maps
    string mapString = gameMaps.getMap(mapNum); // access map from mapnumber
    return mapString;
}

// prints map as string perfectly
int main() {
    cout << Interact::getMap(0);
    return 0;
}
```

this main prints map 0 as a string with no issues when ran

**bindings.cpp**

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <string>
#include "src/json.hpp"
#include "src/Interact.h"

using namespace emscripten;

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Interact) {
   // this builds and retrieves the map in string format
    function("getMapString", optional_override([](int mapNum) -> std::string {
        return Interact::getMap(mapNum);
    }));
}
```

I compile the code with this command:

```
emcc -Os --bind FernQuestBindings.cpp -Icpp src/Interact.cpp src/Maps.cpp -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -o FernQuestInteract.js
```

now when I try to print this string out in the console I get this string -> []

**App.jsx**

```
import fqInteract from './external/fqInteract.js';
import FqInteractWASM from './external/fqInteract.wasm';

const App = () => {
    const[gameEngine, setGameEngine] = React.useState({})
    const[gameEngineLoaded, setGameEngineLoaded] = React.useState(false)


    React.useEffect(() => {
        const interact = fqInteract({
            locateFile: () => {
                return FqInteractWASM;
            },
        });
        interact.then((core) => {
            setGameEngine(core)
            setGameEngineLoaded(true)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
    <div className="container">
        {gameEngineLoaded && console.log(gameEngine.getMapString(0))}
    </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Im having trouble understanding why the string only outputs the brackets but not the contents. Ive tried implementing a wait function to see if that helps (i dont think I did it correctly) I've even had the Maps::getMap function return like "hi" and that string prints out but not the map string, or the map json object which throws an error.

what am I doing wrong. I'm super new to web assembly and emscripten and I have no clue what Im doing

Comment: It looks like you're building a whole lot of potentially expensive temporaries for these functions. Every time you call `Interact::getMap(mapNum)` you call `buildMaps`? That seems... weird. I don't have any familiarity with Emscripten, though, so I can't say if this is leading to the behavior you describe.

Comment: yeah I know its expensive but it was a test to see if it works.. Im still figuring out a way to call non-static functions through web assembly.. that would make it way easier and less taxing (I think)